# Reroute log4j to slf4j

Tags: java, log4j, slf4j

If a 3rd party dependency logs using a concrete framework (such as log4j), and I want my app to do all logging via slf4j, then is it possible to configure log4j (either in XML, properties file, etc.) to redirect the log messages to the slf4j API? (Which, at runtime, would bind to a concrete slf4j binding of my choice.)

It would just be nice to get all log messages going to the same place through the same API.

I don't even mind if I have to do something *a little* crazy, like point log4j.properties to some interim code (that I would write), which in turn directs traffic to slf4j!

I just don't know where to start. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course you can and it is thoroughly explained in the [documentation](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html):

> [log4j-over-slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html#log4j-over-slf4j)
>
> SLF4J ship with a module called `log4j-over-slf4j`. It allows log4j users to migrate existing applications to SLF4J without changing a single line of code but simply by replacing the log4j.jar file with `log4j-over-slf4j.jar`, as described below.

It is both hacky and ingenious - you are removing `log4j.jar` and replacing it with `log4j-over-slf4j.jar`. The latter JAR mirrors Log4J classes in the same packages, so your application and libraries don't even have to be recompiled. But the new implementations are simply rerouting to SLF4J.

Comment: Ahhh, so a slf4j *binding* binds slf4j to some underlying logging system, but a slf4j *bridge* maps/redirects some underlying logging system to slf4j. Is that a fair assertion?

Comment: @herpylderp: yes! Moreover, you must have exactly one SLF4J binding but any number of bridges.

Comment: Warning the `log4j-over-slf4j.jar` is a partial implementation of `log4j` api, so if your library use some classes not implemented in the bridge you will get ClassNotFound errors